# Highcharts:Column Range chart having height of bar same as the height of interval in y Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng, dotnethighcharts, angular2-highcharts

I want to create a columnrange chart type using highcharts.
I have tried something like below:

[image]

- I want to implement the below chart with the following custumization:
  Height of the bars same as the gap between Y axis values as shown in
  image
- Remove the gap between bars.

Comment: This is the URL:https://jsfiddle.net/bp09ax0h/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behavior by fiddling around with [`pointRange`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange) in your `series`

```
series: [{
    name: 'Temperatures',
    data: [
        [-9.9, 10.3],
        [-8.6, 8.5],
        [-10.2, 11.8],
        [-1.7, 12.2],
        [-0.6, 23.1],
        [3.7, 25.4],
        [6.0, 26.2],
        [6.7, 21.4],
        [3.5, 19.5],
        [-1.3, 16.0],
        [-8.7, 9.4],
        [-9.0, 8.6],
    ],
     pointRange: 2
}]
```

In the example I have set it to `2`, as that closes almost the whole gap between bars. 
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bp09ax0h/1/) you can find the working JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Set `pointPadding`, `groupPadding` and `borderWidth` to `0`.

```
 series: [{
  pointPadding: 0,
  groupPadding: 0,
  borderWidth: 0,
  name: 'Temperatures',
  ...
}]
```

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/smqrhn09/